# Error in Reputation Calculation

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation

I hope I am not missing something, but it seems like my reputation is much lower than it should be.
My reputation tab is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662639/user2662639?tab=reputation), I made +182 reputation today, my total reputation is currently 215.
Therefore this implies that prior to today I made a grand total of +33 reputation which is obviously not true.

Comment: You are complaining about too much rep?

Comment: I should have a much higher reputation than is currently being listed.

Comment: @MartinJames Seems to be the opposite.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: your two answer got accepted same time and two upvote on another same time?what a coincidence.

Comment: Your total rep is 325, not 215. (Don't look at your rep figure here on meta, it is cached.)

Comment: @Mat When the OP first asked this question, it wasn't, not even on the main site.

Comment: It looks like it has fixed itself, very strange though. Thanks guys.
(not sure how to close this question myself)

Comment: Since the OP and @Daedalus both claim to have witnessed the wrong number, surely there *is* a bug and the question should be left open (and `status-norepro` put on it if nobody can figure out  what the heck it was)? I'm voting to Leave Open, anyway.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam I don't see any particularly suspicious items there as your comment implies.

Comment: @MarkAmery I also saw the problem.It was about like 1 or 2 hour his reputation point was wrong(215). After Mat's comment I saw it fixed.